# Can I associate seed data for an entity class with the declaration of that class?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-migrations

I have a class called `Planet`. These don't change too often, and neither will the seeding data used to initialise that entity in the database. I don't want to have migration classes with masses and masses of seed data. Is there any other way to hook up seed data for a class than to generate one migration for each such class? E.g. I would like to, in a migration with many entities, add a statement that the seed data for `Planet` is contained in the class `PlanetSeedData`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no proper EF method to do this.  However, you can make your own fairly simply.

Since you would seed data within a migration by calling the `Sql(string)` function, a simple way of moving that out into another class would be to define that class as follows:

```
public static class PlanetSeedData
{
    public static void Seed(Action<string> sql) 
    {
        sql("INSERT INTO dbo.Planets(Name) VALUES('Mercury')");
        sql("...");
    }
}
```

Then call this from your migration:

```
public override void Up()
{
    // CreateTable(...)
    PlanetSeedData(x => Sql(x));
}
```